# How do you put folders into your html websites?

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I want to make an on the go web server with a bunch of videos. I am using the Raspberry Pi to code this. I will download youtube videos and put them in a folder. How do you put a folder of videos into an html website?

Comment: You can't, HTML is not designed to have access to a filesystem ... well HTML is not designed to do anything beside being parsed by a web browser. You can either code something in some server sided programming language (e.g. php) or activate directory listing on your web server (be cautious with this!).

Answer (score 1):

You need to put them into a folder located on your web server. If its locally hosted, i.e, your html files are on the same system as your videos, you should have your file structure looking something like this:

--[FOLDER] - Videos

| -- [FILE] - yourvideo.mp4

-[FILE] - index.html

So your video will be located in /videos/yourvideo.mp4.

You can then call your video in the index.html file. If using HTML5, you can use `<video></video>`:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="/videos/yourvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Answer (score 0):

Name the `.html` `INDEX.html` and make a folder called `INDEX.html_files`
that should work put the videos in the folder then type `/INDEX.html_files/videoname.mp4` as the file name